# How to define an asset for iPad in landscape

Tags: ios, image, ipad, assets

I'm adapting for the first time an iPhone app to iPad. I was glad to see that assets are really powerful when I made the iPad's portrait version. Now I'm working on the landscape version and I realized that some of my images need to be specifically made for landscape.

I'm not sure how to do this. Launch images have landscape variations, but image sets haven't.

How can add a landscape variation in my image set?

Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is a setting in xcassets that will allow you to do this, but here are some strategies:

**9 Slice your images**

```
UIImage *initialImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"someImage"];
UIImage *nineSlicedImage = [initialImage  resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0)];
[self.myImageView setImage:nineSlicedImage]
```

**Set correct image at Runtime**

You can use

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]
```

to check your current orientation

**Set ImageView mode correctly**
In the .xib or .storyboard you can set the mode of a image view to be center/left/right/aspect fit/ aspect fill etc

[image]

remember to set the image view to clip subviews or the image can show regardless of the frame

Comment: My main issue was to set the navigation bar background image, which is not a UIImageView. I ended up creating a second xcasset for landscape and selecting the right one with [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]

Answer (score 0):

you can create a iPad-only xib

i.e, MainView.xib would become MainView~ipad.xib